# correct Sqlite database size calculation

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an app which requires writing many strings to a Sqlite database. During testing i noticed Fatal Exception error is thrown: "Could not allocate cursor window because of db size *always some number bigger than 2000000*" as shown in the link below because of Sqlite database object size grows to more than 2 megabytes.

[CursorWindow can not be allocated because of database size more than 2000000 bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi2f6.png)
Exception is always thrown at cursor.moveToFirst() in the method below:

```
public boolean doesBusinessExist(Business_4s business)
{
    //
    boolean businessExists = false;
    //

    if(business != null) {

        //
        String query = "Select " + COLUMN_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_BUSINESS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " =  \"" + business.get_id() + "\"";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        //

        try {
            //
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                //want to know how many business are there
                int cnt = cursor.getCount();

                //return true
                if (cnt > 0) {
                    businessExists = true;
                }

            } else {
                businessExists = false;
            }
            //
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        }
    }

    //
    //final return
    return businessExists;
    //

}
```

So i decided to write some code not to add more data when db is close to 2 mega bytes, did research again on *how to calculate sqlite db size* and found two ways to do so:

method1:

```
    File f = getDatabasePath("businessDB.db");
    long dbSize = f.length();
```

dbSize value in this method is: 53248 bytes

method2:

```
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler_bus_4s(getApplicationContext(),null);
    SQLiteDatabase db_ =  dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
    long size = new File(db_.getPath()).length();
```

size value in this method is: 53248 bytes

Given that db size is calculated to be 53248 bytes, something is missing in my calculations as i am sure db size is close to 2000000 bytes at this point, so what is the correct way to calculate Sqlite database size in android?

Comment: I don't really know much about android, but the main database file is not the only file in use by SQLite, I think you need to account for the various [temporary files](https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html) as well

Comment: Thanks, but i am not sure how does this solve the problem.

Comment: SQLite writes data to a journal, and depending on pragmas, until a transaction is committed the data might not not have been written in the main db file, so it the total usage can exceed that filesize.

Can I ask why you're not just writing a count query natively but using a cursor?

Comment: You gave me a clue mentioning "total size", i have done some investigation, and looks like you are right, i am going to answer my question

Answer (score 0):

For future travellers:

Based on my observation, total size of **all** SQLite DB's for a certain package can not exceed 2MB (at least by default). My app had 5 SQLite DB's, and as time went on total size of these database tend to get bigger than 2 MB.
The implemented work around was to setup a cleaning service using Alarm Manger to regularly maintain number of records in the databases.

How did i find out? Installed [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) on a rooted phone and navigated to Local>Device>data>data>[app package name]>databases

Also for each database there is another file with .db-journal extension which usually has smaller size than the actuall database but also takes up some space.

[Supplementary image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4s64.jpg)

Comment: Aren't you misinterpreting the error? It is not failing because the Database size is > 2MB (which is tiny) but because the cursor window is too big.